# Getting error while taking mongodb backup from docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, shell, sh

I am getting the following error while taking mongodb backup from docker container using shell script. I am giving the error below.

```
container name : uBot_sandbox_subhrajp
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"mongodump\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Error: No such container:path: uBot_sandbox_subhrajp:/data/ubot-db-mongobackup_2021_02_09_13-09-58
```

My shell script is given below.

```
#!/bin/bash

export DATABASE_NAME="ubot-db"
export BACKUP_LOCATION="/home/UBOT"
export TIMESTAMP=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H-%M-%S')

for NAMES in $(docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}" --filter "name=uBot_sandbox");do
    echo "container name : $NAMES"
    docker exec -t ${NAMES} mongodump --out /data/${DATABASE_NAME}-mongobackup_${TIMESTAMP} --db ${DATABASE_NAME}
    docker cp ${NAMES}:/data/${DATABASE_NAME}-mongobackup_${TIMESTAMP} ${BACKUP_LOCATION}
done
```

Here I need to take mongodb backup from all matched containers and copy those into target location. Please help me to resolve this error and execute the code as expected.

Comment: Check you can run the docker exec and cp commands manually.

Comment: I also run  same `sudo docker exec -it uBot_sandbox_subhrajp mongodump -h localhost -d ubot-db` manually from terminal but its also giving this `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"mongodump\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown` error.

Comment: Try using the full path to mongodump

Comment: Can you please post your answer ?

Comment: I don't know what the full path to mongodump is. You will have to check. Maybe /bin/mongodump?

Comment: Usually I got the container files using `docker exec -it container-name /bin/sh` but here also I can not know what is the full path